# Just installed Ubuntu 14, very bad performance on games, need help

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

So today I installed Ubuntu 14 on my laptop and I tried running counter-strike global offensive, but I only got 30-ish fps, which spikes to 120 sometimes and a lot of stuttering. My laptop has 2 GPUs: Intel HD 4000 and Nvidia GT750m, could it be that CSGO runs on the Intel GPU rather than the Nvidia ? Could use some help as I'm not sure what to do, csgo ran fine on windows 8 at about constant 100ish fps.

Specifications:

- CPU: i7 quad core, 4th gen (don't know the exact numbers, it had MQ
  letters)
- GPU: Intel HD 4000 & Nvidia GT750M
- Memory: 6GBs

Comment: What Graphics driver are you using? Discrete nVidia graphics requires the nvidia-prime feature. If you're using the default driver, open *Software & Updates* -> *Additional drivers* and select the recommended proprietary driver.

Comment: If you want to find your CPU model you can run the command: `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | sed -e 's/model name.*: //'| uniq` and it will tell you.

Answer (score -2):

first of all, i had csgo on my lappy running on win7 64bit, 4gb ram and i used to get around 60fps. So i think the problem here is with linux. Secondly linux is not really for gaming, you should have side loaded it with your windows if you are a gamer.
Now coming to your solution, try changing the windows compability layer software/package you are using. Try "playonlinux" or "wine" or any other and check the fps. 
Sorry but i dont know how to see which video card is being used by linux.